# MySQL query performance slow down suddenly

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a MySQL (InnoDB) database that contains tables with rows count between 1 000 000 and 50 000 000. 
At night there is aggregating job which counts some information and writes them to reporting tables.

Fist job execution is very fast. Every query executes between 100ms and 1s. 
After that almost every single query is very slow.

The example query is:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tableA 
  JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.tableA_id
```

execution plan for that query shows that for both tables indexes will be used.

Important thing is that CPU, I/O, memory usage is very low. 
MySQL server version: 5.5.28 with default setup (just installed on windows 7 developer computer).

Comment: Does the output of `explain select` change before and after the first `select`.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell from the information provided. I am assuming you have done EXPLAIN etc. In a previous experience, one of my queries suddenly slowed down and I realized that a certain field was suddenly populated with a huge amount of data. Instead of using count(*) maybe try count(tableA.id).

See if this helps or provide more information to debug.

Comment: The problem is that this is not only query that slow down. Generally all queries are executed very slow on that database. What kind of information do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, it's not really the query but the writing to reporting tables, which is slow.
I would try two things:

- Measure the performance of the `insert`s or `update`s of your reporting tables
- Reorder your jobs. Take a slow one to the front, to see whether the first job is fast or whether the job, which is run first, is fast

Comment: I removed writing to reporting tables. Now job do only queries and still it is very slow. Also queries do in query browser on that database are very slow. There is no problem with queries to other databases.

Comment: Have you reordered the jobs, to see if anything changes.

Comment: Job is not important in that context (of course I tried to reorder them but did not help), what is important that after running job first time then every single query even from query browser i 20 times slower. During job run about 10000 new records are added to database.

Comment: Then, you could run `analyze table` between the first and second query, to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: This is also what I've tried but always `analyze table` returns status OK